# Do any colleges/universities require professors to provide the library with a free copy of a book they have written while employed by the school?

Tags: publications, books, policy, library

Let's say Professor X, who is currently a tenured professor at Y University, writes a book on genetic mutation. Is it likely Y University has a policy that requires Professor X to supply the university's library with a free copy of their new book on genetic mutation? Does anyone know of any colleges/universities with such a policy? If so, could you cite the source so I can read the policy?

Comment: You seem to misunderstand the nature of tenure. Would it be professional misconduct subjecting the professor to dismissal? That would be a profoundly foolish policy. Libraries might ask, of course, and most professors would be happy to supply one if possible, but it is a minuscule cost to the library to purchase a copy if it is needed - and not all are actually needed. And, of course, the policy would need to be included in employment contracts.

Comment: I was happy to give one copy of my book to each of our two libraries.  If they need more, they can buy more at the standard discount for libraries, and that would make me happy, too.

Answer (score 2):

I have never heard of such a policy at a university.

The UK has what are called '[legal deposit' libraries](https://www.bl.uk/legal-deposit/about-legal-deposit) where, by law, essentially every work published in the country has to be sent to them for free. Other libraries can then request to borrow a copy using an interlibrary loan system. This could easily be confused with a University requirement since three of the six UK legal deposit libraries are the University of Oxford Bodleian libraries, the University of Cambridge Library, and the Library of Trinity College Dublin.

A similar system exists in [many other countries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legal_deposit).

The libraries can turn down copies, so they must be offered and are not necessarily accepted.

Comment: But are they offered by the authors or by the publishers?

Comment: @Buffy generally its the publishers that must provide the copy. But this may vary by country.

Comment: But certainly not a university rule in any case.

Comment: Not a university rule that I'm aware of. But could be confusing in the UK since three of the six legal deposit libraries are the University of Oxford Bodleian libraries, the University of Cambridge Library, and the Library of Trinity College Dublin.

Answer (score -1):

The version I have heard of ...

Any professor may provide copies of his papers (and books, and exhibitions, and performances, and videos, and movies, and compositions, ...) to the university.  These will then be considered in connection with salary increases and promotions for the professor.

So, in this version, professors are not **required** to provide them.  But professors usually do provide them, since it is to their advantage.